# Issues implementing the Fang Algorithm for TDOA Trilateration

Tags: c, algebra, trilateration

I've been following [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-03841-9_21.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A4%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22FitH%22%7D%2C439%5D) (notably the section on Fang's Method) in an attempt to achieve a solution to the problem of trilateration using the [TDOA technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDOA).

I'm hoping that someone experienced in Fang / TDOA can lend me a helping hand. For some reason, my implementation is returning incorrect roots to the final quadratic. Here's the code I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

inline double sqr(double n) {
    return n * n;
}

// r1 and r2 are the TDOA of the sound impulse to p1 and p2, respectively
void fang(double r1, double r2) {
    // transmitter coords
    Point tx = {0.7, -0.1};

    // receiver coordinates
    Point p0 = {0, 0};
    Point p1 = {1.7320508075688772, 0};
    Point p2 = {0.8660254037844388, 1.5};

    // linear coefficients
    double g = ((r2 * (p1.x/r1)) - p2.x) / p2.y;
    double h = (sqr(p2.x) + sqr(p2.y) - sqr(r2) + r2 * r1 * sqr(1 - (p1.x / r1))) / (2 * p2.y);

    // quadratic coefficents
    double d = -(1 - sqr(p1.x / r1) + sqr(g));
    double e = p1.x * (1 - sqr(p1.x / r1)) - (2 * g * h);
    double f = (sqr(r1) / 4) * sqr(1 - sqr(p1.x / r1)) - sqr(h);

    double result_x = (-e - sqrt(sqr(e) - (4 * d * f))) / (2 * d);
}

int main() {
    // these values have been calculated a-priori, from the known transmitter coords
    double r1 = 0.32977743096231715;
    double r2 = 0.90148404145971694;
    fang(r1, r2);
}
```

Ultimately I'd expect the `x_result` to be equal to the transmitter's x coordinate (`tx.x == 0.7`), but frustratingly the result is `≈0.237`.

An outline of my exact problem (and it's solution, where the two hyperbolas intersect) can be viewed geometrically in the below graph:

[image: TDOA graph]

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Hi @KeithMadison, here's a gist with the portion of C code I wrote for my implemenation of TDOA: https://gist.github.com/jonnybrooks/28b8695b9d4ac49f52ed7afd1085c878. If you have any questions, feel free to @ me in the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper gives the following calculation for `h` with the Fang method:

[image: Calculation for <code>h</code>]

Your code incorrectly squares the entire `(1 - (p1.x / r1))` expression, instead of just the `(p1.x / r1)` part. Moreover, you use the wrong values (`p2` and `p1`) instead of the correct ones (`p3` and `p2`). To fix, simply change `h` to:

```
double h = (sqr(p3.x) + sqr(p3.y) - sqr(r3) + r3 * r2 * (1 - sqr(p2.x / r2))) / (2 * p3.y);
```

Comment: In fact the whole line was completely wrong - all the `p2` should be `p3`, and the `p1` should be `p2` - must've been an error when I was doing a find and replace. (I'll edit your answer to reflect the full line) Bounty well deserved!